# What might cause a Views preview to not display?

Tags: 7, views

For some reason I can't preview my views, as shown in this screenprint:

[image]

Any idea what is going on? Maybe it's a setting?

Comment: My guess that it's the `Show: Panels fields` try with `Show: fields`

Comment: If it doesn't help, it never hurts: try to increase your memory limit, eg with 25% or so, and see if you get any difference .....

Comment: It's already under show: fields, how do I increase the memory limit?

Comment: An AJAX HTTP error occurred.HTTP Result Code: 200Debugging information follows.Path: /admin/structure/views/view/articles/preview/page/ajaxStatusText: OKResponseText:

Comment: Actually, ALL my Drupal sites show this error....???

Comment: change jquery version of ur site